# Use strings as parameter names in functions?

Tags: javascript

I've ran into somewhat of unique use case. Given array like this `["option", "option2", "option3"]` I need to export function that looks like

```
function myFunc(option, option2, option3) {  }
```

parameters of such functions are dynamic, I need to populate them based on given string array, I'm fine with mapping through it, but am stuck at step where I convert string like `"option"` to parameter name like `option`

Comment: Are you looking for `Spread Syntax`?

Comment: Are you asking about [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)?

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to do this? What is the problem you're trying to solve? Parameter names generally don't matter and are not important for how a function is actually called.

Comment: Can you use the "Arguments" object?   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: This sounds like a typical case of why the [`Function.prototype.toString` censorship proposal](https://github.com/domenic/proposal-function-prototype-tostring-censorship) exists.

Comment: This is one of those times when I can't help forming a little mental cartoon of somebody typing in a question and then immediately shutting down the computer and running out into the woods.

Comment: One upvoted answer. One downvoted answer. Four deleted answers. Wow. (People thinking about answering, read the question *carefully*! (Who am I kidding, those people probably won't read the comments anyway)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you **can** do that, I strongly recommend you **don't**. It requires using `new Function` or `eval`, which is normally worth avoiding as it fires up a JavaScript parser (and in the wrong hands, exposes a vulnerability by offering arbitrary code execution). I'd just export a version that accepts a single array parameter rather than discrete parameters. People can easily call it with discrete arguments: `myFunc([firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue])`.

But ***if*** the text in the array **comes from a safe source**, you can do it with `new Function`.

In ES2015+:

```
function realMyFunc(options) {
    // ...`options` is an array of the parameters
};
export const myFunc = new Function(...theArray, "return realMyFunc([" + theArray.join(", ") + "]);");
```

Example:

```js
const theArray = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];

function realMyFunc(options) {
    console.log(options);
};
const myFunc = new Function(...theArray, "return realMyFunc([" + theArray.join(", ") + "]);");
console.log("myFunc:", myFunc);

myFunc("a", "b", "c");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or in ES5:

```js
var theArray = ["option1", "option2", "option3"];

function realMyFunc(options) {
    console.log(options);
};
var myFunc = new Function("return function(" + theArray.join(", ") + ") { return realMyFunc([" + theArray.join(", ") + "]); }")(); // Note the added () at the end
console.log("myFunc:", myFunc);

myFunc("a", "b", "c");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Again, though, I'd just export a version that accepts a single array parameter rather than dynamically generating a version that accepts discrete parameters.

Comment: *(Doh! The text of the generated function was missing `[` and `]`; fixed now.)*

Comment: Before this answer, I didn't know that functions can also be created this way. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: @31piy — Can be. Shouldn't be. See the first sentence of this answer :)